# Stress Testing ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net, stress-testing

what are different ways that we can do some optimum level of stress testing for asp.net application before moving it to the production environment ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here is the free tool for the stress testing in asp.net application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alikl/stress-test-asp-net-web-application-with-free-wcat-tool

Another is called asp.net performance engineering which will tell how we can stress application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alikl/asp-net-performance-engineering-stress-test-your-architecture-design-and-code

Also go through the following post:

[Best way to stress test a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340564/best-way-to-stress-test-a-website)

From my experience before moving to the production environment please take of following things.

1. set debug=false into the web.config
2. set trace enabled=false into the web.config
3. Always use precompiled version of your code.
4. Compile your project into the release mode.
5. Publish your code if you are using asp.net 2.0 or higher version
6. User caching api as much as possible.
7. Decrease your html kb.
8. remove blank spaces from the asp.net html code.
9. Use stylesheet as external .css file
10. USE IIS Compression if poosible.
11. Put your javascript file in .js files
12. Use Server.Transfer instead of Response.redirect
13. Use Inproc Session State if possible.
14. Use Viewstate efficiently- Use controlstate instead of viewstate which is newer feature in asp.net 2.0
15. Avoid giving big name to controls it will increase your html kb.
16. Use Div instead of tables it will decrease your size.
17. Do IIS Performance tuning as per your requirement

Here is the good link that teaches us good way of deployment in production environment.

http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/dsdaf/111222006014732AM/1.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful checklist. I have pretty much addressed all the points mentioned by you. for viewstate we use http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20040613.asp which makes our viewstate completely off-page delivering a lighter html.

I am not sure what you mean by "6) User Caching API" and this is the only thing which i have not taken care of as well.

Comment: ASP.NET Offers a cache api. For more details about cache api. You can find lots of stuff in asp.net.Here are the some good links.
http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/12/30/cachingaspnet.html
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20060407.asp
http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webapps/aspcachingfeatures.aspx

Comment: `Use Server.Transfer instead of Response.redirect` huh

Answer (score 6):

Apache JMeter (http://jmeter.apache.org/) is an excellent tool for stress-testing web applications.  It can be used with any web server, not just Apache.

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio 2010 provides some fantastic Test Automation tools and also for Load Testing the web applications.