# Testing approach in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, performance, testing

I'm working with an application developed using ASP.NET in C#.

I would like to perform a stress test on the page load, server resources usage and other statistic.

I've tried using System.Diagnostics class StopWatch, which return the time taken to load the program.

Any other suggestion or approach for testing the page performance? for example, let say got more than thousand of users accessing the page, will the page hit performance issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836608/stress-testing-asp-net-application